# Browser tries to load even if all the content are rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written code in node js to render a html file. But, the browser still tries to load the file, even if it is completely rendered.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var reqHandler = function (req, res) {

 if (req.url == "/") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);
    }
};

http.createServer(reqHandler).listen(3000);
```

What is wrong in the above code?

I think I got the problem, but don't know how to solve this. The index.html file contains a javascript file. When I commented the script tag, the browser loaded the html file correctly. But when the script tag is included the browser is stuck. I think the browser needs the javascript file. How do I send the javascript file?

Comment: working fine on my windows machine ... if you are working on linux then try to change the directory permissions !

Comment: works on Mac. Not sure what "still tries to load the file" means.  Which browser and what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying on windows machine and chrome browser. There is a circle near the title of the web page and keeps on rotating. Same thing is happening in firefox. And at the bottom I can see a message "Waiting for localhost"

Comment: You have to end the response using `res.end()` to end response from the server

Comment: Thats not working. I think I got the problem, but dont know how to solve this. The index.html file contains a javascript file. When I comment the script tag the browser loads the html file correctly. But when the script tag is included the browser stuck. I think the browser needs the javascript file. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to handle requests for the JS file, and any other "unexpected" requests (like `/favicon.ico` that most browsers will request under the hood) by sending back a 404 (*"Not Found"*):

```
var reqHandler = function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);
  } else if (req.url === '/script.js') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript' });
    fs.createReadStream('script.js').pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
  }
};
```

Obviously, this is going to become pretty tedious if you want to add more files, so modules like [`node-static`](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static), [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) or even a framework like [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/index.html) may be useful.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.